# Can you append strings to variables in PHP?

Tags: php, string, operators

Why does the following code output 0?

It works with numbers instead of strings just fine. I have similar code in JavaScript that also works. Does PHP not like += with strings?

```
<?php
    $selectBox = '<select name="number">';
    for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
    {
        $selectBox += '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
    }
    $selectBox += '</select>';

    echo $selectBox;
?>
```

Comment: [Reference for PHP operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? The question asks for appending a string in a special case with a further more specific question about the output of the code.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This is because PHP uses the period character `.` for string concatenation, not the plus character `+`. Therefore to append to a string you want to use the `.=` operator:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    $selectBox .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
}
$selectBox .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 23):

In PHP **use `.=` to append strings**, and not `+=`.

> Why does this output 0? [...] Does PHP not like += with strings?

`+=` is an arithmetic operator to add a number to another number. Using that operator with strings leads to an automatic type conversion. In the OP's case the strings have been converted to integers of the value `0`.

---

**More about operators in PHP:**

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/4137828)
- [PHP Manual – Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Comment: `$selectBox = '<select>'; $selectBox += '</select>';` Expands to `$selectBox = '<select>' +  '</select>';` PHP converts strings to `0` if they don't at least begin with numbers. Hence `0+0`

Answer (score 2):

PHP syntax is little different in case of concatenation from JavaScript.
Instead of **`(+) plus`** a **`(.) period`** is used for string concatenation.

```
<?php

$selectBox = '<select name="number">';
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    $selectBox += '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>'; // <-- (Wrong) Replace + with .
    $selectBox .= '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>'; // <-- (Correct) Here + is replaced .
}
$selectBox += '</select>'; // <-- (Wrong) Replace + with .
$selectBox .= '</select>'; // <-- (Correct) Here + is replaced .
echo $selectBox;

?>
```