# Push items in a string with "+="

Tags: php

Can somebody tell what I'm doing wrong

```
$str = "";
$str += "Was het maar vrijdag";
$str += "Was het maar zaterdag";
echo $str;
```

this return 0

Comment: this is Java, not PHP...

Comment: `+` is numeric addition; `.` is string concatenation

Comment: You should concatenate with . instead of +

Comment: Seems like a lot JAVA guys are moving to PHP. Welcome Aboard!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you append strings to variables in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050685/can-you-append-strings-to-variables-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use dot `.` instead of plus `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` instead of `+`:

```
$str = "";
$str .= "Was het maar vrijdag";
$str .= "Was het maar zaterdag";
echo $str;
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. I am voting up. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use .=

In PHP, strings are attached with ., not with +

```
$str = "";
$str .= "Was het maar vrijdag";
$str .= "Was het maar zaterdag";
echo $str;
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. I am voting up. +1

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, thanks, dont know either what i did wrong.^^